# $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous $\Rightarrow f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

$f(x)$ is uniformly continuous $\Rightarrow f'(x)$ is uniformly continuous

I've encountered with an example which is basing on this statement.

Is this statement true?

Comment: Did you tried to find any counter example?

Comment: Your question is missing crucial information, e.g.: Is $f$ a real-valued function of a real variable? Are you assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere?

Comment: I believe $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$ is a counterexample ($f'$ isn't even continuous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about $F(t)=\int^t_0 \sin(x^2) dx\,$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Any continuous function defined on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: $f'$ need not be continuous.

Comment: @DavidMitra, sorry but what is the idea behind your comment. I post this hint, so Op can see the possibility of a continuous function with discontinuous derivative. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1)$.